# Object explorer disappeared in Mictosoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, view, toolbar

The MS Visual Studio Object Explorer toolbar disappeared all of sudden.

The shortcut F8 and the view->object explorer did not help.

Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Ctrl + Alt + D and it works!